# Хранение сортировки объектов

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, node.js

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите какое-нибудь решение для такой задачи: есть карточки, которые выводятся на экран в виде списка. У карточек есть порядок, при их создании им выдается  `ordr = max_ordr+100;` для текущего списка. Эти карточки DnD можно таскать и когда мы бросаем карточку между двух других, ей соответственно выдается `ordr = (prev_ordr+next_ordr)/2`, т.е. физически ставим ордер ровно по середине между них. Проблема в том, что за конечное число перемещений, значение с плавающей точкой достигает своего предела и вся эта сортировка перестает работать. Кто нибудь может подскажет, как реализовывали хранение порядка объектов?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте хранить карточки в виде двухсвязного\односвязного списка, как вам удобнее.
В этом случае всегда можно вставить новый элемент списка в любое места, не сдвигая   остальные элементы.